# Nonrepetitive nonhomogenous partition regularity

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, colorings

> Is it true that for every $k$ for every $k$-coloring of the natural numbers there are naturals $a_1,\dots,a_{2l}$ for some $l\ge 2$ such that $a_1+a_3=2a_2+2$, $a_2+a_4=2a_3+2$, ..., $a_{2l-2}+a_{2l}=2a_{2l-1}+2$ and the color of $a_i$ and $a_{l+i}$ are the same for every $i$?

Motivation. Such a sequence is called a repetition. Nonrepetitive colorings have been studied a lot, going back to the [Thue sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence). Recently, a variant of the problem was raised for Euclidean spaces at EuroComb'23 by [Barsse, Gonçalves, Rosenfeld](https://journals.muni.cz/eurocomb/article/view/35550). This is an attempt to solve some questions left open with a trick from this classic paper of [P Erdős, R.L Graham, P Montgomery, B.L Rothschild, J Spencer, E.G Straus](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(73)90011-3). That is where the +2 comes from, without which the $a_i$'s would form an arithmetic progression, so the statement would be true by van der Waerden, even giving all monochromatic $a_i$'s. We cannot hope to get all monochromatic $a_i$'s when the +2 is there, as shown by Erdős et al. There might also be some relation to [partition regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_regularity).

Comment: Van der Waerden's theorem would give, in the version without the $+2$, that the statement is true for every $l$. You are asking for some $l$, which seems much weaker. Is that what you intended?

Comment: That is also a nice question, probably equivalent to mine, but for the application I have in mind, it is enough to find just any one $l\ge 2$. (I added the $\ge 2$ condition just now, it was missing.)

Comment: If the colors are the residue classes modulo $3$, then there is no such sequence for $\ell=2$. So $\ell$ should really depend on something. May it happen that $\ell$ depends on $k$ only? (I think the other fixed values of $\ell$ can be discarded similarly.)

Comment: @Ilya So are you proposing the stronger conjecture that for every $k$ there is an $l$ such that for every $k$-coloring there are $a_1,\ldots,a_{2l}$ such that ... ?

Comment: Basically, I just replied to Sam Hopkins' comment --- we cannot hope to prove this for any specific $\ell$ and *all* $k$. I don't think the stronger conjecture holds in fact, I heavily doubt that even what you want is true...

Comment: What do I *want*? I conjecture that the answer to my question is no. That would have an application as it would show that a nonrepetitive coloring exists in the setting of Barsse, Gonçalves, Rosenfeld. A yes answer would have no applications, AFAIK.

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry. Then it seems to me that what you want is true;), although I cannot prove it.
A very rough motivation is as follows. The colors of each quadratic sequence $(i%2+pi+q)$ should  form a square-free word. There are plenty such words, if $k\gg 2$. Surely, such sequences intersect, but their intersections are quite sparse, as they are solutions of some Pell-type  equations. So there is a hope to arrange all this.